# How do you figure out if the currently running RSpec test is a failure?

Tags: rspec

From outside the context of the spec files, how/can you figure out how to get the current example, and inspect its metadata?

[I'm trying to get VCR to not record](https://github.com/vcr/vcr/issues/274) if the test fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSpec doesn't currently provide a public API for accessing the current example (because it has no notion of a globally accessible current example internally), but it's fairly trivial to expose this on your own using a global `before` hook:

```
RSpec.configure do |rspec|
  rspec.before(:each) do
    $current_rspec_example = self
  end
end
```

Then you can access the current rspec example using `$current_rspec_example` from anywhere.

Comment: True, can do something like this. Thanks!